# QuillField not showing in django admin

Tags: django, quill

[Quill editor](https://github.com/LeeHanYeong/django-quill-editor) v0.1.40 works fine on my local computer, but when in production, QuillFileds are invisible on admin panel – only labels appear:

[image]

When inspecting the admin page on Chrome, I see such errors on the console:

```
GET https://my site.com/static/django_quill/django_quill.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET https://my site.com/static/django_quill/django_quill.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught ReferenceError: QuillWrapper is not defined
    at (index):261:27
    at (index):263:11
```

**django_quill.css** and **django_quill.js** fail to load. I can't figure out why it works on my local project which has the same setup, except that on local I use python 3.9/Django 4.0.1 while in production, it's v3.8/4.0.2.

Another difference is that, in production, **django_quill** folder is under `myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` directory.

On my computer, there is no **django_quill** folder under `myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/`. In fact, there is no such folder anywhere on my drive, nor the related **django_quill.css** or **django_quill.js** files.

I have no problem while migrating from old TextField's, or viewing the content on the templates.

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my development settings, static configuration was as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

Whereas on production:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/root'
```

Which was a mistake, of course. *STATICFILES_DIRS* shouldn't be present on production. So I changed it to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
```

and ran *collectstatic*. Now it works fine.